# Wrong vector selected mouse-clicking on computed layer

Tags: qgis, select, virtual-layer, sql-view

[qGIS 3.10.14]

Only on computed layer such as virtual or spatialite view:

When simply clicking in canvas (or using any other gui/spatial selection method) to select particular feature(s), what gets highlighted/selected are never the feature(s) actually at the cursor position, but features situated elsewhere.

It is maddening. Right now I'm just trying to select and copy to a working layer one property parcel from a spatialite view that links 60+k polygons with appraisal attributes. But clicking on the parcel highlights and selects in the attribute table a parcel that sits clear across the county. Clicking and dragging or selecting by polygon/freehand similarly selects distant parcels.

Yet when I export the layer to non-virtual form (shapefile, spatialite table), the resulting layer works fine.

I've tried every combination I can think of for project and layer CRS because it feels like that's the likeliest cause, but I'm not fluent enough in projection and transformation to get a handle on it. Also I've searched high and low on this forum and others, to no avail.

Comment: (Sorry, new at this.)
qGIS 3.10.14

Comment: In trying to anticipate questions I might be asked to help diagnose, I've identified the source of my problem which has nothing to do with CRS.
It's definitely a problem with my misuse of SQL joins. Clicking a selection generates a subset of records each with a sequential ROWID starting with 1. What gets selected from the master set is the record set with matching ROWIDs.

Now I'm down to trying to figure out how to edit spatialite views, which doesn't seem to be a thing in qGIS' dbase manager.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are complaining that Qgis selects different feature on canvas other than that you clicked. You should select the layer in "Layers Panel" before selecting its features on the map.

Comment: Xi Jin thank you, but that's not what is happening. There is only one layer in the entire project -- there is no other layer to mistakenly select in the Layers panel or to return an unintended feature.

With that one layer selected in the Layers panel, clicking on or otherwise selecting any feature in that layer always returns a completely different feature from within that one layer. The feature will be Row #1. Selecting two features will return the two wrong features in Row #1 and Row #2.